# Android Cannot Connect to Server to Register or Login

Tags: java, php, android, laravel, android-volley

I have an android app that is using Laravel backend and I am using Volley to connect for register and log in.

Although it works fine with Postman but in the app when I try to register it gives me this error:

```
E/Volley: [1266] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://star.magossa.com/api/register
W/System.err: com.android.volley.ServerError
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:205)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:131)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59a04c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf5cde570)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf59a04c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf5cde570)
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

```
private void register(){
    dialog.setMessage("Loading");
    dialog.show();

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.REGISTER, response -> {
        //We get response if connection successful
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            if (object.getBoolean("success")){
                JSONObject user = object.getJSONObject("user");
                //make sharedpreferences user
                SharedPreferences userPref = getActivity().
                        getApplicationContext().
                        getSharedPreferences("user", getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPref.edit();
                editor.putString("token", object.getString("token"));
                editor.putString("name", user.getString("name"));
                editor.putString("lastname", user.getString("lastname"));
                editor.putString("photo", user.getString("photo"));
                editor.apply();
                //if successful
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Register Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    },error -> {
        //error if connection not successful
        error.printStackTrace();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }){
        //add parameters

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

            map.put("email", txtEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            map.put("password", txtPassword.getText().toString());
            return map;
        }
    };

    //add this request to request queue
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to the question?

Comment: I added register function,, I would like to tell you that Login function works well and connect to server properly

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check and confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting because your API requires name, email and password but you are sending only email and password, modify getParams and add name as well. See the example:

```
   @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("email", txtEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            map.put("name", name_from_input);
            map.put("password", txtPassword.getText().toString());
            return map;
        }
```

Comment: Awesome man it worked .. I really forgot about name field. Thank you @AlphaOne

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Comment: @ AlphaOne Can you tell me please how did you find that my API requires name field in register .. because I do not see this in the code I posted above?

Comment: I created a dummy post request with email and password to your server https://star.magossa.com/api/register using postman. It displayed HTTP 500 error with message name is null.